# Changing Target Framework SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

In order to change the Target Framework for script tasks in SSIS 2012 using VS2012, I can only see how to do this by changing it in every script task. Is there any way to change this for all tasks in the project at one time?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Script Task or Component to an SSIS package, there is a template in your installation folder that SSIS uses.

For 2012, it'd be in 
`Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn`

In there, you have a VSTA11_IS_ST_CS_Template.vstax file which is just an uncompressed zip.

1. Unzip that somewhere safe,
2. Modify line 14 of `IS%20Script%20Task%20Project.csproj`
3. Rezip it without compression
4. Copy it back into the source folder

I blogged a similar approach with [Slimming down the SSIS Script Task](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/slimming-down-ssis-script-task.html)

The specific attribute you're looking to modify in the project file is

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

What you wanted to change it to, you never specified

Comment: Will this only work for new script tasks? I originally created this project using SSIS 2008 and now upgrading to SSIS 2012 and want to target .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Ah, no. Sorry if I misread the question. This only works when you add a new to to your package. For modifying existing tasks, you're likely looking at having to use the SSIS object model to change them out. I've modified plenty of SSIS objects through the object model except for the script stuff. Sadly, it hurts my head to try and grok it